# What is the widest tire I can fit on my 32c wheels?

Tags: tire, cyclocross

I have Shimano WH RS30 rims which are 700c x 32.  I would like to use a beefy 35c tire.  Is that too much width for my rims?

(My forks and brakes are wide enough to handle a 42c)

Thank you.

Comment: [These rims](http://www.shimano.com/publish/content/global_cycle/en/us/index/products/wheels/road_wheels/product.-code-WH-RS30.-type-.wh_road.html)? They say they're 622x15C. The bead-seat width is the relevant measure, not the rim height.

Comment: The specs show 20.8mm width. I'm wondering the same thing, I have a RS-30 wheelset and want to run 700c x 37 tires.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that your rims are actually 622x15 ISO size, like the Shimano page for those rims says...

According to [this handy chart on Sheldon Brown's site](http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html#ETRTO), putting a 35mm tire on a 15mm rim is slightly bigger than recommended. It's close enough that it should be fine, however. That chart is fairly conservative (and even says so at the bottom).

As far as *the widest*, you could put 42mm on there if the fork, brakes, stays, bridges and seat tube all have the clearance, but that's really pushing it quite far and likely to cause poor handling or other issues. 35mm is just barely pushing it and should be fine.

Comment: You're right.  They're 622x15.  Thanks for clearing that up for me.  I appreciate the opinion, there's no local bike shop where I live.

Comment: Nice reference! +1

Answer (score 0):

I've seen and used tires with more than twice the width of the rim without issues.
Using a 35c tire on a 32mm wide rim should be no problem.

Besides that, it is interesting to note that here

http://www.shimano.com/publish/content/global_cycle/en/us/index/products/wheels/road_wheels/product.-code-WH-RS30.-type-.wh_road.html

it says these rims are 522x15c, and the rim width is 28mm... Are these the same model as yours?

Comment: You got it, they're 622x15s.  I suppose rim measurements were not clear to me before.

Comment: Well, using a 35 tire on a rim with overall width of 28mm should be no problem either ;o)